# What shortcuts can I use in the Visual Studio Find textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2008, there's a "find" textbox in the tool bar at the top of my screen.  If I type in

```
>of myfile.vb
```

into that box, it will open myfile.cs (assuming it's in my project).  I find this to be about the fastest way to open a file, because I don't even have to move my hands from the keyboard.  I can open a file faster than I could get my hand to the mouse. Are there any other time-saving shortcuts I can use in the "find" textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it to execute any command no just >of.

Some commands I find useful:

```
>immed - opens immediate window if I missplaced it
>callstack - same but for callstack
```